# Why does v6v4tunnel not work on hyper-V guest?

Tags: hyper-v, windows-10, tunneling

I'm attempting to setup up a Windows v6v4tunnel on Windows 10 Build 14393. Creating the tunnel is straight-forward.

```
netsh interface ipv6 add v6v4tunnel interface=IP6Tunnel 192.168.1.12 xx.xx.128.26
netsh interface ipv6 add address IP6Tunnel 2001:xxx:xx:70::2
netsh interface ipv6 add route ::/0 IP6Tunnel 2001:xxx:xx:70::1
```

When I attempt to create the tunnel on Windows 10 running as a Hyper-V guest it does not work. For testing I have disabled all firewalls. I am using a single network adapter which is shared with the OS.

For testing I attempted creating the tunnel on a standalone PC, on the same network, and it works without issue. I also created the tunnel on the Hyper-V host itself and it also worked correctly. This rules out any network, firewall, or NAT issues. I only have issues run attempting to create the tunnel on a Hyper-V guest. This does not appear specific to Windows as I also attempted to create the tunnel on an Ubuntu guest.

How can I debug this further and get my tunnel running correctly?